# passing data from list view to detail view in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I have a typical CRUD app with separate routes and controllers for the list view as well as the detail views.

The data for the list is retrieved using a `$resource`.

Currently in my detail view controller I fetch the item from the server using the `$resource` which results in an extra http request.

Instead, since in my list controller I already have the item that I am editing, I would like to pass this item from the list controller to the detail controller.

But I do not know how. I can make one single controller for both views but this does not seem right.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a service to share data between controllers:

exemple: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/IjKY_CRyRno/kP0M_LTzOTkJ

or a fiddle I wrote some time ago: http://jsfiddle.net/XqDxG/169/

```
myModule.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {
    var sharedService = {};
    sharedService.data = {};
    sharedService.data.message = '';

    return sharedService;
});

function ControllerZero($scope, sharedService) {
    // expose service data to angular scope
    $scope.sharedData = sharedService.data;

    $scope.handleClick = function(msg) {
        sharedService.data.message = msg;            
    };

    $scope.$watch('sharedData.message', function(msg) {
        $scope.message = msg;
    });
}

function ControllerOne($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.sharedData = sharedService.data;

    $scope.$watch('sharedData.message', function() {
        $scope.message = 'ONE: ' + sharedService.data.message;
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks, in the factory you attach a dictionary to $rootScope. But the aim of a shared service is to avoid root scope  pollution. So if I have to attach something to the root scope, I could just as well not use a shared service but use $rootScope directly, no? Could you explain this?

Comment: yes it's bad design you're right, you should attach the service data in the controller scopes from the controller code :)

Comment: This seems overly complicated.  Here is a very basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/HarzR/

Comment: Yes if you just need data and not a full service depending on other injects .value() is a good fit.